# Unable to locate element or switch to frame

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm following this YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGU2X5lrz9M) for an Instagram bot but it keeps giving me the error

```
Unable to locate element:
```

I can't figure out what's wrong and everything I've found about the issue says to switch to frame or iframe but the guy in the tutorial doesn't have to do that and I also can't figure out how to switch. Please help me out!

Here's the code

```
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
    time.sleep(2)
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[2]/p/a')
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    username_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="f2fdc3b5774d3f4"]')
    username_elem.clear()
    username_elem.send_keys(self.username)
    password_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="f25923ff3b40138"]')
    password_elem.clear()
    password_elem.send_keys(self.password)
    password_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not about frame but the element `ID` for input form is changed

[image]

it safer to select `by name`

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

login_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log in')
login_button.click()
time.sleep(2)
username_elem = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username_elem.clear()
username_elem.send_keys(self.username)
password_elem = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password_elem.clear()
password_elem.send_keys(self.password)
password_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(2)
```